# get all likes from facebook v4

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to get all likes from facebook through android:facebook-v4.How can I get all likes in one go .Or is there any other way to paging in one go ? I am currently using the code below and I get only 25 at a time.

```
GraphRequest request2 = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {

                                    JSONObject  uu= response.getJSONObject();
                                    if (uu!=null){
                                        Log.w(TAG, "respomse: " + response.toString());

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters2 = new Bundle();
                    parameters2.putString("fields", "likes");
                    parameters2.putString("limit", "999");
                    request2.setParameters(parameters2);
                    request2.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get all likes in one API call, you need to implement paging to get more results: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

You can do this with a recursive function, for example.

Comment: So what do I need to add to the above code? Should I call asynctask for each http:// till I get only previous ? I appreciate the extra help.Thanks

Comment: exactly, the value in the "next" field of the api result is the api call for the next batch. if "next" is empty or does not exist, you´ve reached the end.

Comment: I tried this code but I am getting errors as this is not working with new fb v4 . How can I do the same with the new code in fb android ?. JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
        String next = jsonObject.getJSONObject("paging").getString("next");
}
//for next friend
// before using next remove the graph api path from it. i.e  "https://graph.facebook.com/"
    Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), next, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {}

Comment: @luschn: can you suggest any cheap way to get this result? For example in case of millions of like, we have to make (millions/25) api calls, which would be not easy.

Comment: well, you can increase the limit a bit, although there is a max limit (not sure how high exactly). increasing it to 100 should be no problem. so you get 100 per call. but if you got millions of likes, it may still be a problem and there´s no way around it. you can get a large batch, wait for a while and get the next batch. for example.